# Apache Drill application is taking too long time to execute

Tags: hadoop, apache-drill

I am storing  data in HBase and it has 3.5 million records. I am using Apache Drill Java application to query this hbase data, but simple queries are taking 3 min to complete.

I allocated drill_direct_memory=10GB and drill_heap=8GB. How can I get fast query performance? Am I missing any configurations or any changes I have to do for getting better performance?

This is my sample query:

SELECT CONVERT_FROM(row_key, 'UTF8') AS row_key,CONVERT_FROM(social_data_nlp.details.user_name, 'UTF8') AS user_name,
TO_CHAR(CAST(social_data_nlp.details.created_time AS TIMESTAMP), 'yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss') AS created_time FROM hbase.social_data_nlp WHERE  CAST(social_data_nlp.details.created_time AS date)>DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE,1) AND (social_data_nlp.details.searched_keyword = 'fire' OR social_data_nlp.details.searched_keyword = 'accident' OR social_data_nlp.details.searched_keyword = 'karnataka' OR social_data_nlp.details.user_name = 'aajtak') AND CAST(social_data_nlp.details.keyword_search as boolean) =true ORDER BY social_data_nlp.details.created_time DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0;

Comment: You can put a timer to measure the time that takes the hbase to take the rows, compute them and show them. If your database is long it is the normal time that apache takes.

Comment: My database has 35 lakh records and drill order by query is taking 170 sec to complete.Can you please suggest me how to improve this.

Comment: this is a link on how to optimize, if you already did this way is normal to take that long https://community.mapr.com/docs/DOC-1497-apache-drill-best-practices-from-the-mapr-drill-team

Comment: anybody have any idea other than this please share me.

Comment: Please share an example "simple query" you are quering.

Comment: Vezir I added sample query in the above question,please go through that one and suggest me what I have to do.